# How to do df.rdd or df.collect().foreach on streaming dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, spark-structured-streaming

This is the exception I am getting whenever I am trying to convert it.

```
val df_col = df.select("ts.user.friends_count").collect.map(_.toSeq)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

All I am trying to do is replicate the following sql.dataframe operations in structured streaming.

```
df.collect().foreach(row => droolsCaseClass(row.getLong(0), row.getString(1)))
```

which is running fine in Dataframes but not in structured streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collect` is a big no-no even in Spark Core's RDD world due to the size of the data you may transfer back to the driver's single JVM. It just sets the boundary of the benefits of Spark as after `collect` you are in a single JVM.

With that said, think about unbounded data, i.e. a data stream, that will never terminate. That's Spark Structured Streaming.

A streaming Dataset is one that is never complete and the data inside varies every time you ask for the content, i.e. the result of executing the structured query over a stream of data.

You simply cannot say "Hey, give me the data that is the content of a streaming Dataset". That does not even make sense.

That's why you cannot `collect` on a streaming dataset. It is not possible up to Spark 2.2.1 (the latest version at the time of this writing).

If you want to receive the data that is inside a streaming dataset for a period of time (aka *batch interval* in Spark Streaming or *trigger* in Spark Structured Streaming) you write the result to a streaming sink, e.g. `console`.

You can also write your custom streaming sink that does `collect.map(_.toSeq)` inside `addBatch` which is [the main and only method of a streaming sink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Sink.scala#L40). As a matter of fact, `console` sink [does exactly it](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/console.scala#L51).

> All I am trying to do is replicate the following sql.dataframe
>   operations in structured streaming.
>
> ```
> df.collect().foreach(row => droolsCaseClass(row.getLong(0), row.getString(1)))
> ```
>
> which is running fine in Dataframes but not in structured streaming.

The very first solution that comes to my mind is to use [`foreach` sink](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach):

> The `foreach` operation allows arbitrary operations to be computed on the output data.

That, of course, does *not* mean that this is the best solution. Just one that comes to my mind immediately.

Comment: I got it resolved by implementing forEachWriter and trigger.

Comment: @hadoop mind sharing your `addBatch` method? I'm in a similar situation

Comment: @maverik there's no `addBatch` method when `foreach` is used. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@foreach(writer:org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[T]

Comment: I tried exactly this, but my Databricks notebook cannot find the wrapper class in which I defined `addBatch` (might be a notebook bug) hence looking for a fully self-contained example. If you publish one in your gitbook, it could be a valuable addition for lots of spark users struggling to fit ML models on a Streaming batch! Cheers

Comment: @maverik Can you elaborate on _"the wrapper class in which I defined addBatch"_? What's the wrapper class?

Comment: I got around that bug, you just have to define class and instantiate it in different notebook cells. Here's a relevant question that I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163211/cannot-evaluate-ml-model-on-structured-streaming-because-rdd-transformations-and

Comment: I need to use the output of a `foreach` sink (adds values to a `Set`) to load a DataFrame from a Postgres database (i.e. JDBC source) and then join the same microbatch with this DataFrame and write the joined DataFrame to a final sink. Is that possible?